# Slow connection when more than one device is connected

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I am having a weird problem !

When only one device is connected to my WiFi network the speed is very good, but when I connect another device to WiFi, speed will go below 2mb/s and 900ms ping time !! My internet speed is 25mb/s

One of the devices is desktop PC and another one is Surface Pro 2 (both Windows 8.1)

There is not anything downloading in background !

Whats the problem ? I have tried changing WiFi channels and it didn't help, the comcast support couldn't help me, they just told me maybe there is a problem with their router and I should change it !

Comment: If it is their router and they are offering to change it, why not just do so?

Answer (score 0):

It is worth checking whether the computers are speaking to each. There may be so much chatter on the network that it causes other traffic to deteriorate. That is one possible reason why this occurs only when more than one device is connected to the network. That also may explain your observation that they are not downloading anyting in the background.

To see if that is the case, download the free Wireshark packet capture utility. Run it on your network adapter on both machines and close down all your programs. Of course, every machine is different but if you only a hundred or so packets a second on each machine then that's not bad. If it sends thousands a second then it would mean your networking gear is taking a hit.